# How can I save the custom option value in Magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1

[image]

> How can I save this custom value in database and get in the cart page with the custom option ?

Comment: When you add custom option, it is already saved in database and also shown on cart page.

Comment: @krishan Patadia i have to add two fields when click custom option i want to add these two field in database

Comment: Which two fields ?

Comment: i added  one  custom  option and two value one is free and second is payed and i have to add two fields in payed  one is option and other is textarea how i save these two fields

Comment: This is your product custom option or just field ? @Rahulocodewire

Comment: @Keyur Shah in product option i have to make two fields with java script i want to save these two fields with the custom option.

Comment: @ Keyur Shah can you please tell me how i save these two attribute value i have to make one attribute and make two two value on is free and second is payed if user click in payed option and open two fields i want save these two fields with attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use, `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` event because this event triggered just before the product with its custom options is converted to a quote item.

In this event you can get added product object `$product` object by using,

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
```

Now you can add your custom option like,

```
$infoOptions[] = array(
                            'label' => "YOUR_OPTION_LABEL",
                            'value' => "YOUR_OPTION_VALUE",
                        );
```

you can update this option according your requirement,

Now just add this custom option like,

Add this custom option by

```
 $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($infoOptions));
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212462/product-add-to-cart-before-i-want-to-set-product-custom-option-values-in-magento/212465#212465

Comment: keyur shah - here two products created. why this happen any idea?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212523/product-add-to-cart-before-custom-option-dublicate-product-create-in-magento2