# Product Add to cart before I want to set Product custom option values in Magento2.2

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, addtocart

I want to add product to cart with some product already create custom option values put. So what happen current magento create new product in cart while same product different custom options or values. I need same product but values increment.

Product in already created 2 custom options and not required so Add to cart before I want to put both custom options custom values. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php#L613) event to add custom option before adding product into cart.

In this event you will get product object like this,

`$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();`

and then you can set your custom condition If its satisfy then you can add your custom option

```
      if (someconditon == true) {
        $infoOptions[] = array(
            'label' => "YOUR_LABEL",
            'value' => "YOUR_VALUE",
        );
        $product->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($infoOptions));
    }
```

Comment: Hi but in cart page showing me error like that - Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

Comment: yes magento2.2.2.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value - is useful?

Comment: thanks answer works but cart page two seprated product created. -
 nimb.ws/vFUtlK

Comment: Where is this additional information saved, in quote_item_option?

Comment: @Magento2Devloper did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet still we leave it